# How can we get a Twitter list to be crawled / published as HTML?

Tags: twitter, twitter-integration

As far as I understand, when we embed a Twitter list on our site the Google bots won't crawl it or index it because it's javascript based and doesn't participate of the site's HTML.

If your website relies on Twitter lists this is a huge disadvantadge.

How can we "import" a Twitter list into a website as content in HTML?

I have been searching the internet but there seems to be no tutorial about it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't get crawled because it is embedded as an iframe. Pretty much all oembed content is put into an iframe of some sort. Technically it's not page content, it's another URL embedded into a page.

If you wanted to make it indexable you would need to at least copy and paste it into your page.Or hopefully do something a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Google isn't interested on content published firstly on another page as yourth. If you just want your twits are indexed - publish links in your twits. Google is always keen on getting new links.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google new updates, you cannot post other page content on your webpage. Your post should be unique only then Google will crawl whether it is on Twitter or any other social media.